# Sketching hemisphere in Matlab using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code, which is an attempt to sketch z=sqrt(4-x^2-y^2) using cylindrical coordinates. Granted, spherical coordinates would be much more appropriate, but my question involves what is happening with the following code.

```
r=linspace(0,2,20);
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,40);
[r,theta]=meshgrid(r,theta);

x=r.*cos(theta);
y=r.*sin(theta);
z=sqrt(4-x.^2-y.^2);

mesh(x,y,z)
```

### >> ver

MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
Operating System: Mac OS X  Version: 10.9.5 Build: 13F34 
Java Version: Java 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 with Apple Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

The above code will not plot due to the following error.

```
Error using mesh (line 76)
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex
```

I find it strange that all values of the matrix z are expressed in complex form. After all, I am plotting the surface over the region x^2 + y^2 <= 4. For example, a few values:

```
z =

  Columns 1 through 3

   2.0000 + 0.0000i   1.9972 + 0.0000i   1.9889 + 0.0000i
   2.0000 + 0.0000i   1.9972 + 0.0000i   1.9889 + 0.0000i
   2.0000 + 0.0000i   1.9972 + 0.0000i   1.9889 + 0.0000i
   2.0000 + 0.0000i   1.9972 + 0.0000i   1.9889 + 0.0000i
```

If we do a:

```
format long
```

Then view some of the last entries of matrix z, which are in column 20 of z (calculated when r = 2), we see:

```
  0.000000021073424 + 0.000000000000000i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.000000021073424i
  0.000000021073424 + 0.000000000000000i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.000000014901161i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.000000010536712i
  0.000000007450581 + 0.000000000000000i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.000000013938760i
  0.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
```

Which indicates to me some sort of roundoff error going on. For example:

```
>> z(39,20)

ans =

      0.000000000000000e+00 + 1.393875996311732e-08i
```

This I believe is with:

One way this problem can be cured is as follows:

```
clc
close all
r=linspace(0,2,20);
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,40);
[r,theta]=meshgrid(r,theta);

x=r.*cos(theta);
y=r.*sin(theta);
z=sqrt(4-r.^2);

mesh(x,y,z)
```

But this doesn't work.

```
clc
close all
r=linspace(0,2,20);
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,40);
[r,theta]=meshgrid(r,theta);

x=r.*cos(theta);
y=r.*sin(theta);
z=sqrt(4-(x.^2+y.^2));

mesh(x,y,z)
```

Gotta be roundoff errors, correct?

Comment: Yep, roundoff errors I think. If you do `z=real(sqrt(4-x.^2-y.^2));` then it works fine. Your idea of `z=sqrt(4-r.^2)` is neat though!

Comment: Agreed, it's roundoff errors. If you add a call to `real` as David suggests, you should be set